# Не обновляються данные в Mat-table Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

У меня есть таблица, где я обновляю данные:

```
startEdit(row, i) {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditCategoryComponent, {
    data: {id: row.id, name: row.name}
  });

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if(result === 1) {
    this.back.getData().subscribe(res => {
      const foundIndex = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(x => x.id === res.id);
      this.dataSource.data[foundIndex] = res;
    });
  }
});
```

}

Но ресурс dataSource в таблице не измениться, но если выводить через конструкцию

```
*ngFor
```

То всё работает прекрасно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MatTableDataSource` или любой кастомный источник данных, который наследует этот класс - имеет сеттер `data`. `data` - это не массив, это геттер, который определен  в классе `MatTableDataSource` и возвращает текущее значение генератора событий с кешированием:

```
get data(): T[] {
  return this._data.getValue();
}
```

Где `_data` это:

```
this._data = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>(initialData);
```

В свою очередь сеттер `data` генерирует новое событие для подписчиков под капотом:

```
set data(data: T[]) {
  this._data.next(data);
}
```

Во-первых давайте избавимся от подписки внутри подписки, так как это анти-паттерн:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
  filter((result) => result === 1),
  mergeMap(() => this.back.getData())
).subscribe((response) => {
  ...
});
```

Не забудьте импортировать операторы:

```
import { filter, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

В колбеке не нужно пытаться мутировать `data` по индексу, нужно сеттить само свойство:

```
subscribe((response) => {
  const index = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(({ id }) => id === response.id);
  const data = [...this.dataSource.data];
  data[index] = response;
  this.dataSource.data = data;
});
```

Также не забывайте, что `findIndex` возвращает `-1` если не находит элемент массива по предикату, чтобы исключить этот вариант добавим еще фильтрацию:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
  filter((result) => result === 1),
  mergeMap(() => this.back.getData()),
  map((response) => {
    const index = this.dataSource.data.findIndex(({ id }) => id === response.id);
    return { response, index };
  }),
  filter(({ index }) => index > -1)
).subscribe(({ response, index }) => {
  const data = [...this.dataSource.data];
  data[index] = response;
  this.dataSource.data = data;
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Очень грамотно просветили меня в этом. Я признателен